# How Remove Gmail Attachments In Place Without Deleting Email?

Tags: gmail-api

I'd like to do the following with the Gmail-API.

Open a gmail message (Can do now)
Read the contents (Can do now)
Read the attachments (Can do now)
Update the message body (HOW TO DO?)
Remove the attachments and Update the existing email (HOW TO DO?)

My question is How to do the "HOW TO DO?" above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify://) explains that you can only modify the **labels** of the message. You won't be able to update the message body. In any case, what you are required to do is to [get the message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) data and save it, then [delete the message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete) and finally [insert the message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) again with the attachments removed. I hope this information helps!